# ASUS laptop won't boot without strange sequence

Tags: battery, asus-laptop, repair, water-damage

Model: Asus M7400Q

The laptop got a bit wet today. I let it dry and cleaned out the motherboard with isopropyl alcohol (although nothing looked damaged), but it wouldn't boot. Plugging in the connector didn't turn on the lights, but did seem to charge the battery. After following the following sequence the laptop booted:

1. Unplug battery
2. Press power button for ~30s
3. Connect battery again
4. Connect AC adaptor

Observations:

1. Once the battery is removed, it works fine on AC. Connecting AC with battery does not.
2. The laptop refuses to shutdown once turned on and will always reboot immediately after turning off.
3. As mentioned above, charging still works despite lack of indication.
4. Once the sequence is completed, the laptop works fine off battery and drains as expected
5. As mentioned, the indicator lights don't turn on at all, but they do work after following the sequence. A hard shutdown will cause them to stop working again, and the laptop won't boot without redoing the sequence.

I couldn't find any apparent damage and it everything works fine once booted, but it will no longer boot without this sequence! Could it be related to the CMOS battery?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It is hard for anyone here to concretely say what the issue is.  You need to get it serviced by ASUS or a local shop

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry you are not the first nor the last to do this. I'd recommend removing the battery from laptop and leave unplugged for 24 hours to allow to dry all of the internal components that got wet. Do not use any more alcohol or "wipe it down" with something to try to dry faster. It simply needs to air dry and it should be fine tomorrow.

Comment: If the batteries (power and clock cell) are left in a computer that has become wet, electrolytic corrosion can occur. As suggested, **let it dry thoroughly**. If that does not fix the issue, then professional repairs are needed. *91% or stronger* isopropanol probably did not hurt it, though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The water exposure was very minimal (a couple of drops). After drying both with cold air and over night the issue hasn't resolved, but I'll go to a professional.